# Mysql 5.0 certification Certs

Tags: mysql

I have just got the MySQL 5.) certification guide .I am a programmer analyst using Cobol Cics Adabas natural and wish to know what test is required to take after I complete studying the book ..

I also ordered this book
The only Oracle Press exam guide for Oracle OCP MySQL certification
OCP MySQL 5.6 Database Administrator Exam Guide covers all of the exam objectives on the OCP level exam for MySQL DBAs in detail. You can become MySQL certified by passing OCP Exam 1Z0-883. This book prepares you for this highly technical exam and focuses on practitioner-level skills, covering a broad set of topics, including security, backup, replication, and optimization. 
Ideal as both an exam guide and on-the-job reference, each chapter of this Oracle Press book includes examples, practice questions, lab questions, and a chapter summary. An Exam Readiness Checklist appears at the front of the book—you’re ready for the exam when all objectives on the list are checked off. Two-minute drills at the end of the chapter reinforce knowledge. Inside the Exam sections in each chapter highlight key exam topics covered. 150+ exam questions match the format, topics, and difficulty of the real exam. 
•   Covers the single exam required to achieve OCP certification for Oracle MySQL—Exam 1Z0-883 
•   Electronic content includes two interactive practice exams and a PDF copy of the book 
•   The electronic exams also feature an open-book mode with hints, references to the book, and detailed answers and explanations

Comment: You can buy a voucher from this page [1Z0-883](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=652&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-883). Please correct title 5.0 -> 5.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you studied this book

[image: ThisBook]

you may want to wait on taking a Certification Exam. Why ?

I certified with that book back in August 2007, when MySQL 5.0.27 was the latest version.

I have mentioned this book in some of my posts

- `Jun 22, 2012` : [The Value of Certifications](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200/the-value-of-certifications/19758#19758)
- `Aug 19, 2011` : [Best Book to Learn MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/best-book-to-learn-mysql/4825#4825)
- `Jul 09 , 2011` : [Suggest a MySQL book for me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/suggest-a-mysql-book-for-me/3749#3749)

Notwithstanding, so much has changed since then.

For Example, these things are not mentioned in this old book

- [Row-based Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/row-based-binary-logging.html)
- [GTID Binary Logging Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-howto.html)
- [Read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [Write](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) IO Threads
- [Buffer Pool Instances](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances)
- [Dumping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown) and [Loading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup) the Buffer Pool to Disk on Reboot

These are available in MySQL 5.6.23 (Current GA Release). It is in your best interest to read the MySQL 5.6 Documentation first.

When you do get the new book

[image: newBook]

read it through but be prepared to send it back if it is just a verbatim quote of the MySQL Documentation.

Whether you keep the book or not is your choice. Nevertheless, read the latest info for MySQL 5.6, get decent hands-on experience with MySQL 5.6 (at least 1 year). Then, take the exam.